# GUI Library: How long should it take to write one from scratch?

Tags: c++, user-interface

For a *single* C++ programmer, how long *should* it take to write a GUI framework from scratch?

Rough specification:

1. You have access to boost, image loading functions, font rendering routines, signal-slot, unicode string classes, varaint classes. (basically Qt 4 minus actual gui (everything derived from QWidget)).
2. You'll have to implement standard controls like treeviews, table views, text editors, list box, combo box, buttons, radio buttons, panels, etc.
3. The framework is separated from operating system and does not use any OS objects (window handles). I.e. you operate on raster image or on OpenGL window and receive mouse/keyboard events from OS you have to dispatch/interpret.
4. There are multiple windows that can be moved/minimized/maximized, brought to front.
5. It should be possible to use the library to reimplement any rectangular window using this library (think Win98 gui with animation effects disabled).
6. You are not required to display html pages.
7. You can't cut corners, make bitmap in ms paint, blit it onto screen and say "it is a window". Components have geometry, configurable color, can be resized, "anchored" to different sides of the window, linked to each other and affect each other's sizes and geometry (think Qt 4 layout system).
8. Programmer's skill - average to above average, at least 3 years of C++ experience.

Basically, "Windows desktop" without using windows gdi.

I am asking because I'm working for guys that develop something like that from scratch (their needs are very unusual, and afaik no existing gui framework I know matches them), and I have a suspicion that I might be working too slowly, which negatively affects my "morale".

Previous people wasted 3 years on this project (they wrote it in Delphi) and have failed to complete it, so the guy in charge decided to scrap it and start over from scratch. Project is very different from traditional guis, but should have somewhat identical complexity.

So I need a rough estimate (with arguments or based on work experience) from another programmer for comparison.
*My* estimate is that it would take around 1 year or longer, but I'd like to know whether that is too long.

Comment: Considering your reputation I'm a bit surprised about such a question, as it is totally subjective and prone to wild guessing. YOu already know that it is a huge task, and takes quite a lot of time, though I wouldn't really try to make a guess how long it takes until it becomes stable.

Comment: @Devolus: My estimate is "1 year or more". However, I need alternative opinions at the moment. The dude I work for expected decent prototype in 3 months, and I managed to miss this mark. So I want to reevaluate situation and figure out whether it is my fault or it was unreasonable expectation and nothing could be done about it. That's what the question is for.

Comment: 'huge task' is probably an underestimate.  'their needs are very unusual, and afaik no existing gui framework I know matches them', together with 'Basically, "Windows desktop" without using windows gdi' is very worrying.  If 'The dude I work for' is expecting decent prototype in 3 months, update your CV now.

Comment: Learning how to estimate project scope would be on-topic for programmers.se.  Having us estimate your scope for you is on-topic nowhere.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've already been working on this thing for months, so it is not really about "estimate your scope for you". I just needed different perspective. The "boss" (non-programmer, afaik he's an ex-engineer) is not really happy that it takes too long and has a quite annoying habit of telling me that "this could've been avoided by better planning". Since I can't figure out how to do this thing any faster, I've been worrying that maybe I'm losing my skills or something. I was told that the company is not in any danger because of the slow development, though.

Comment: This is a very good, realistic question, with sufficient motivation and detail. Probably you could ask from the perspective of what exactly is lacking based on the boost features you mention, and limit the functionality you ask to a bare core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29), development of Qt began in 1991 with two developers. They founded Trolltech in 1994. The initial Qt release was one year after in 1995, so it's at least 2 man years at full time (1994-1995) plus any time they spent on it before 1994.

The thing is, when they founded Trolltech, they probably already had a decent-enough product to take the financial risk of a company so those 2 additional man years are just the tip of the iceberg. And depending on the investment they were able to leverage, they may have hired other people to help them, too.

Even if you take into account all the core functionality that isn't GUI-related (the easiest part to write, IMO) and use a very optimistic estimate, that's still several man years for the initial GUI-part of Qt. Quite far from the 3 months your boss expected from you...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, given you invest a week of time planning the structure of the library and gathering together all of the features you want to include in it, you could potentially complete it in 6 months.  This all depends on the amount of extensibility you want  for it, but I think a year is too long.

This, of course, is all under the assumption of several years of experience with C++ and some experience in GUI design.  It would also benefit the resulting look-and-feel if you or a co-worker had experience with graphical design in something like Photoshop to create the various UI skins.

I hope this helps.